# Implementing a mathematical formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematical-optimization

I want to implement the following mathematical formula in python:

> optimal[i][s]=max{ optimal[i+1][s], optimal[i+1][s-J[i]] + V[i-1] 
>   (s>J[i])}

I tried the following:

```
W={1:3,2:2,3:1,4:4,5:5,6:9,7:6,8:7}
V=[25,20,15,40,50,55,45,58]
optimal=[[]]
J=list(W.values())
s=12
for i in range(1,len(W)):
    while J[i]<s:
        optimal[i][s]=max(optimal[i+1][s],optimal[i+1][s-J[i]]+V[i-1])
print(optimal)
```

But i get an ERROR saying:

> List index out of range.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but `optimal` is an empty list and you are trying to access non-existent elements from it. To add elements to an empty list use `extend()` or `append()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulation is similar to dynamic programming. If you search with dynamic programming and python keywords, you can find good examples. Especially https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/ 
and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20569/dynamic-programming-knapsack-solutionhttps://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/